# How can i merge two datasets with similar words in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook, dataset

For instance i have a row value on the dataset_1 :
"Entity" = Apple

dataset_2 :
"Entity" = iCloud Apple

(Entity is the column)
I need to merge one dataset to the other by the column entity, but to do that i need them to have exacly the same value and Apple ≠ iCloud Apple.

Both datasets are huge so i cant do this manually, one by one.

[dataset_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nOLdc.png)

[dataset_2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/blidi.png)

Comment: To have a better help you could provide an example of your dataframe and an example of the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
`
# preparing data
dataset_1 = {"Entity": 'Prudential Insurance Company of America - Unisys', 'Bank': 'America'}
dataset_2 = {"Entity": 'Unisys', 'Bank': 'Africkan', 'code': '70000-000'}
ds_array = [dataset_1, dataset_2]
# end of preparing data

for d1 in ds_array[0:len(ds_array) - 1]:
    n1 = d1['Entity'].split()
    n1 = {x for x in n1 if len(x) >= 5} # discards words with less than 5 letters
    for d2 in ds_array[1:len(ds_array)]:
        n2 = d2['Entity'].split()
        n2 = {x for x in n2 if len(x) >= 5}
        merge = n1 & n2 # only words in both sets: n1 and n2
        if len(merge) > 0: # tests if there is at least 1 word
            d1['Entity'] = ' '.join(merge)
            d2['Entity'] = d1['Entity']
print(ds_array)
`
```

Output:
[{'Entity': 'Unisys', 'Bank': 'America'}, {'Entity': 'Unisys', 'Bank': 'Africkan', 'code': '70000-000'}]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it didn't help me much.

Comment: I modified the code after understanding the real need! Entity became unique for both rows. Does it continue without helping?